# Какой буфер лучше использовать Delphi

Tags: delphi, файлы, буферизация

Подключила буфер для **чтения и буфер для записи** файла:

```
Var
  fall, f1: TextFile;
  S: string;
  Buf1: array [0 .. 2048 * 2 - 1] of byte;
  Buf2: array [0 .. 2048 * 2 - 1] of byte;

Begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    AssignFile(fall, OpenDialog1.FileName);
    reset(fall);
    system.SetTextBuf(fall, Buf1); // буфер для основного файла Fall
    AssignFile(f1, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName) + '\Rezultat.txt');
    rewrite(f1);
    system.SetTextBuf(f1, Buf2); // буфер для записи файла f1
  end;
  while not Eof(fall) do
  begin
    ReadLn(fall, S);
    // И тут идет чтение из fall и запись текстовой информации в f1
    writeln(f1, S);
  end;
  CloseFile(fall);
  CloseFile(f1);
```

И вот вопрос - **Какой буфер лучше использовать и какой оптимальный размер буфера?**. Спрашиваю потому что они одинаково работают и никаких отличий нет. Но, **скорость**, при использовании буфера - выросла в разы.

**Вариант №1**

```
Buf1: array[0..2048*2-1] of byte;
Buf2: array[0..2048*2-1] of byte;
```

**Вариант №2**

```
Buf1: array [0..2048*2-1] of char;
Buf2: array [0..2048*2-1] of char;
```

**Вариант №3**

```
Buf1: array[word] of char;
Buf2: array[word] of char;
```

**Вариант №4**

```
Buf1: array[0..2048*2-1] of Integer;
Buf2: array[0..2048*2-1] of Integer;
```

Comment: `Buf1: array[word] of char;` а так можно? И в целом я бы советовал byte использовать. Или char (что впрочем по сути одно и тоже). И, возможно, стоит использовать средства ОС для копирования файла или открывать в бинарном виде.

Comment: @pavel, Думаю что да. У меня при таком варианте  также работает. Вот с этой темы, этот вариант взяла: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639351/Работа-с-огромными-файлами-out-of-memory-delphi

Comment: Чтобы быстрее работало нужен blockread blockwrite использовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Безразлично, как объявлять.

Это лишь предоставление куска памяти подсистеме работы с текстовыми файлами, так что играет роль только размер.

Comment: Тогда еще такой вопрос: Если устанавливаю размер 2048, 4096,8192 то разницы в скорости никакой. Разница только между 1024 - 8192. То есть если 1024 то скорость меньше. Но почему нет разницы в скорости между 2048 и 4096 или 8192 ?.

Comment: @Татьяна это зависит от скорости вашего винчестера, настроек файловой системы и прочих радостей. Нельзя сказать однозначно сколько нужно. но 4КБ вроде бы стандартненький такой.

Comment: Наступает насыщение, когда скорость чтения уже не лимитирует. Физический сектор - минимальная единица чтения с жёсткого диска - обычно 4096, с этим может быть связано.

Comment: @MBo, то есть, по сути дела, больше чем 4096 и нету смысла ставить, как по стандарту - получается...

Comment: @pavel, А параметр  * 2 - 1 как то влияет на скорость в данном случае ? Или можно ставить по стандарту array[0..2048].

Comment: [0..2048] - не "круглый" размер.

Comment: @MBo, извините за глупый вопрос. А не круглый размер [0..2048] это что ? То есть в каком смысле, то есть нужно выставлять [0..2047] или ?

Comment: @Татьяна Да, массив [0..2047] состоит из 2048 элементов, т.е. ровно 2 КБ (2 в 11 степени).

Comment: @zed, Понятно, а то я поначалу чего то не вникла. Уже разобралась, благодарю.

Answer (score 3):

Может, стоит уже уйти от работы с текстовыми файлами по старинке? Если по какой-то причине вас не устраивает `TStringList` и ему подобные классы, пользуйтесь `TStreamReader`:

```
var
  tsr:TStreamReader;
  s:string;

<...>

  tsr:=TStreamReader.Create(filename,TEncoding.ANSI, false, 16384);
  while not tsr.EndOfStream do
    begin
       s:=tsr.ReadLine;
       <...>
    end;
  tsr.Free;
```

Я привёл вариант конструктора, когда вы можете выбрать и формат строк и размер буфера. Но можно оставить все по умолчанию, вызвав другой конструктор:

```
tsr:=TStreamReader.Create(filename);
```

В этом случае размер буфера будет задан по умолчанию размером в 4096 байтов.

Данный подход проще и быстрее, нежели работа с файлами по старинке, плюс позволяет работать с кодовыми страницами. Для записи можно использовать класс `TStreamWriter`. Кстати, последний удобен ещё и тем, что можно легко записывать в файл в строковом виде любые переменные, используя метод `WriteLine`.

Comment: `Данный подход проще и быстрее`  - это не подтверждается [`тестом`](https://ideone.com/AKJpWL). Текстовый файл  анси 500 мегабайт читается за 5 секунд Readln c буфером 4096 (10 сек с буфером по умолчанию). А стримридер тратит  9(буфер 1024), 11 (4096), 27 секунд (указанный буфер 16384)

Comment: @MBo Речь была не о скорости непосредственного чтения, а о скорости и удобстве (класс содержит ряд возможностей "из коробки") разработки (совместимость с .NET и нативные методы для систем хранения данных, сбора информации и научных приборов). По скорости, кстати, проверю на работе, мои студенты в своё время мне рапортовали об удовлетворительных результатах. P.S. Closefile и обнуление суммы, вообще-то, в вашем тесте надо внести внутрь замера времени :P

Comment: Я так воспринял, что скорость работы обеспечивается повыше, и решил проверить. Скорость вовсе не плохая, просто немного хуже. Внести можно, но это ничтожные величины.

Comment: @MBo Ну, вот протестировал на работе. Как ни странно, на моей станции, StreamReader медленнее на 12% в 32-битном и на 8% в 64 битном режиме. Однако, на сервере, где у нас идёт счёт, и где стоит RAID из 7ми SSD, StreamReader быстрее на 4%. С размерами буфера не игрался, в качестве текстового файла брал геном человека (3.5 Гб) Видимо, сказывается зависимость от аппаратного обеспечения/ драйверов. У нас к некоторым приборам в комплекте поставки внутри SDK есть StreamReader.dll

Comment: Интересно, только тип накопителя повлиял, или ещё что-то - например,  на сервере может стоять Xeon, для которого работа с памятью и арифметика того примитивного парсинга, что разбирает данные по строкам, могут иметь совсем другие соотношения, чем на i5/7.

Comment: @MBo Сервер на ThreadRipper'е. Посмотрю, есть ли StreamReader.dll в комплекте драйвера RAID

Comment: А какое отношение StreamReader.dll драйвера  имеет к дельфийской реализации?

Comment: @MBo Никакой. Но если есть, стоит попробовать работать через него, как мы делаем с некоторыми анализаторами, - просто используем класс из библиотеки. И сравнить скорость, разумеется :)

Comment: а эта библиотека предоставляет функции для чтения строк или просто некое буферизованное чтение блоков данных, оптимизированное под конкретные накопители?

Comment: Наверное, нас скоро погонят из комментов :) Собственно, конкретики для обсуждения особой нет, информацию об альтернативных методах чтения и сравнимой скорости получили, так что надо заканчивать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85639/discussion-between-viktor-tomilov-and-mbo).